# Unable to login second time in iOS app

Tags: ios, authentication

I m new in iOS field. And i am work on Login and Logout process in my app.
I am logging in using the Api @"xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"

And i got the response

```
{ msg = "Sucessfully Login";
    "session_expiry_time" = 1400828396;
    "session_token" = 4e873000ca2229a9f613a8cede9a68d2;
    status = Success;
    "user_id" = 624;
}
```

and then i save the response data in `NSUserDefault` and when i click on the logout button then make the  `"session_expiry_time"`  and `"session_token"` = null.

But after that i try to login with different username and password then i am unable to login. And getting the response

```
{

 msg = "Invalid Email address or Password"; 
 status = Failed;

}
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: What API are you trying to log into? This sounds like some specific behavior of that particular web service.

Comment: r u using any 3rd party api?

Comment: no ,in case of logout i m not using any api.

Comment: is there requirement of any Api for logout?

Comment: Can you login a second time using the same username and password you used the first time?  It looks like your second account credentials are incorrect

Comment: Yes, I can login second time with same username or password,But if i use the second account credentials first time after rum the app then that work  and then any other account credentials not work.

Answer (score 0):

Exact solution is that Put a break point on login button and go ahead step by step and check the value that you are sending. It might be server side problem . So please check it by put a break point there.

Comment: I use the break point ,Every value is coming but in response {Stats = failure}

Comment: Then Please logout it from server side. Server saved the session value. Until unless you wouldn't clear session value, it will show same error. And please check that after logout your username still occur in database or not.

Comment: Ok , so my guess was right :) So my suggestion was helped you or not ?